# What does the 'count' function do in App Engine search expressions?

Tags: python, api, google-app-engine, search

in SortExpressions and FieldExpressions. One of the functions available to use in those expressions is `count(field)`documented here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/overview#Expressions?

It says it looks for the number of values for a certin field, but does that mean you can assign a list of field name, or use the same field name multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

> does that mean you can assign a list of field name, or use the same
>   field name multiple times?

It means neither.  It returns the total number of matching records in a query.

Use it like `COUNT(*)` in [SQL queries](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp).